# Meteor - data not being inserted into database

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-methods

Hey guys i got my second web-app up and running on my local enviroment, it works pretty much flawlessly, but when I use

`meteor deploy kortmotmenneskeheten.meteor.com/`.

I have a Meteor.methods that i use to let to let users create a new game, it's supposed to add a new game to the database, but it seems to have no effect on the database. Here is the Method:

```
"newGame": function() {
  console.log("gameCount: " + Games.find().count());
  console.log(!Meteor.userId());
  if (!this.userId) {
    console.log("error is being thrown");
    throw new Meteor.Error("UserNotLoggedIn", "You are not logged in");
  }

  console.log("kden");
  try {
    console.log("game: " + {
      players: [
        createPlayer(null, "master")
      ],
      owner: Meteor.userId(),
      ownerName: Meteor.user().username,
      board: createBoard(),
      master: Meteor.userId(),
      createdAt: new Date()
    });

    gameId = Games.insert({
      players: [
        createPlayer(null, "master")
      ],
      owner: Meteor.userId(),
      ownerName: Meteor.user().username,
      board: createBoard(),
      master: Meteor.userId(),
      createdAt: new Date()
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
  }
  console.log("gameID: " + gameId);
  return gameId;
},
```

There is obviously a lot console.log() statements added for debugging, they indicate that the Method is being run up until the try block, I'm kind of at a loss, any help or pointers appreciated.

Edit: Also, after I run the Method, you can't log out off your account.

[Github repo](http:////https://github.com/hakosl/cards-against-humanity)

[The site deployed on meteor servers](http://kortmotmenneskeheten.meteor.com/)

Comment: What a mess. Where is the `createPlayer` function and what does it do? How about `createBoard`? Does it actually create something? You're executing both twice. Are you publishing and subscribing to all the collections involved?

Comment: yes, of course, check out my [methods file](https://github.com/hakosl/cards-against-humanity/blob/master/server/lib/gameAndPlayerManagment.js), i dont really know what the best practice is for doing large inserts into mongodb in meteor is.

Comment: The functions return return objects which i use to store the state off the board, and the players. the console.log() statement logs the entire object that I'm supposed to be inserting into mongodb, but it doesn't seem to get that far anyways, also sorry for splitting this into two comments, but SO wont let me edit my comment again.

Comment: This is a lot to debug. @Christian is right that you need to use `this.userId()` instead of `Meteor.userId()` in your methods. Can you try just getting just one object to be inserted before you move on to inserting all the objects at once? Making a `players` collection doesn't seem to make much sense btw unless it is n:1 with `users` and not just 1:1.

Comment: I did replace Meteor.userId() with this.userId. anyways im not sure what you mean with 1:1 and n:1, it's many players per game, i just add the rest of them in a different Method, because not all players are going to join at the creation of the game, [anyways here is an example game document that i inserted on my local enviroment](http://imgur.com/cBIMyhu)

Comment: [Ooops, here is the correct image](https://imgur.com/1DK5Up3)